# Computed property setter creates Maximus stack exceeded

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have such code:

```
<div id="app">
   <b-form-group label="Sorting">
     <b-form-checkbox-group
        v-model="sorting"
        :options="filterData.sorting"
      />
   </b-form-group>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    sorting: {
      get: function () {
        return this.filterInput.sorting
      },
      set: function (value) {
        // this array needs to always have only one value
        this.filterInput.sorting = [value[0]]
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      filterData: {
        sorting: ['PRICE_ASC', 'PRICE_DESC']
      },
      filterInput: {
          sorting: []
      }
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pum86bsx/1/

Error seems to be in computed getter. When I comment it out it's all good. I have no idea why it's like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You setting the value of the v-model (the value returned in the getter), which will cause the setter to fire again.. and again.. and again.. Causing your stack to overflow.

#### Using checkboxes

You could instead use the `@change` event, which should only fire when the value actually changes.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
   return {
     filterData: {
       sorting: ['PRICE_ASC', 'PRICE_DESC']
      },
      filterInput: {
       sorting: []
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
   onChange(value) {
     if(value.length === 0) {
    this.filterInput.sorting = value
      } else {
       this.filterInput.sorting = [value[value.length - 1]]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-form-group label="Sorting">
     <b-form-checkbox-group
      v-model="filterInput.sorting"
      :options="filterData.sorting"
      @change="onChange"
      ></b-form-checkbox-group>
  </b-form-group>
</div>
```

#### Using radio buttons

Alternatively you could use radio buttons, which only allows one to be selected at a time, so you don't have to handle that yourself.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
   return {
     filterData: {
       sorting: ['PRICE_ASC', 'PRICE_DESC']
      },
      filterInput: {
       sorting: []
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-form-group label="Sorting">
     <b-form-radio-group
      v-model="filterInput.sorting"
      :options="filterData.sorting"
      ></b-form-radio-group>
  </b-form-group>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to understand - how getter is setting value? Shouldn't it just read it?

Comment: It's mostly just a guess at what's happening. The getter returns the value to `b-form-checkbox-group`, which then shows the value. When you  then click on a checkbox, that fires the setter. Which changes the `filterInput.sorting` prop. And since this value changes, it recomputes the getter. `b-form-checkbox-group` then registers the change and goes to `set` the value again. This basically creates a infinite loop.

Comment: The issue is that `b-form-checkbox-group` doesn't check if that value *actually* changed, when using `v-model`. It only check the reference, and since you create a new array with a new value it will get a new reference (even if the array contains the same values). Unlike the `@change` event, which check if the values inside the array is different, and only fires if that's the case.

Comment: Seems like https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter is not complete then. Thanks a lot for thorough explanation - now I need to implement it.